# what is the exact difference between different types of treee traversing

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, tree-traversal

how do I choose how should i traverse a tree
in-order, pre-order, post-order?

I understand what is the difference between those, but what is the practical difference?
Time complexity?

thank you..

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do... For example, in-order is used to retrieve all the contents in ascending order.

Comment: Belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of traversal you should use really depends on what it is you are trying to do.

For example;

**Postorder** would be used when deleting a tree, as a node can only be deleted after is left and right subtrees have both been deleted.

**PreOrder** would be used when you want to copy a tree, as the parent node needs to be created before you can create subtrees for that particular node.

Hopefully this will help you : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/618/